# I'm a little nervous about seeming arrogant (Solved)

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Is there a better way of saying 'is that okay?' or is that phrase itself okay to use. I'm just worried about appearing arrogant, It's never been mentioned that i could be until my last 1 to 1 with my boss... so please help.

Comment: The question "Is that ok?" is not, by itself, arrogant. To the extent that it's *requesting* permission or affirmation, one could make the case that it's humble or self-effacing. But of course, like all utterances, inflection, intonation, body language, and above all else, *context* make all the difference. Can you provide more of the conversation you intend to have?

Comment: Of course, I'm proposing to put a document onto a site my company use. The email it is part of goes:

Hi guys,

I’m going to upload the new Call Recorder V3.1 Pricelist onto the Portal. Is that ok?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.  To be perfectly safe, you may wish to substitute *planning* for *going*.

Comment: Just embrace your inner arrogance and be done with it!

Comment: how do I post that this question was solved? sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context, but in general you could say 'if that suits you' to be more polite.

For example instead of "I would like to meet at 11, is that okay?" you could say: "I would like to meet at 11, if that suits you".